# Extract section from json in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json string where some part of it needs to be extracted and sent to a service. I am wondering if it's possible to extract that specific part in jquery using expressions or any other approach?

the sample json I have is

```
{"hashcode":[], "stringMap":{":id":"50",":question":"My roof"}, ":size":"2", ":type":"java.util.HashMap", ":typeId":"123"}
```

and the string I want out of it is

```
{":id":"50",":question":"My roof"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Thanks for Inputs guys. I just realized that stringMap may have an arbitary name, like stringMap_0 etc.. can I still get that part out without exactly know that name?

thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be clear here that JSON is just Javascript Object Notation. So what you have is several objects:

```
{"hashcode":[], "stringMap":{":id":"50",":question":"My roof"}, ":size":"2", ":type":"java.util.HashMap", ":typeId":"123"}
```

Breaking this code down further, we find the following:

```
"hashcode":[] //an empty array named hashcode

"stringMap":{":id":"50",":question":"My roof"} //an object named stringMap with two properties, ":id" and ":question" (not sure why the : are there, this is abnormal)

":size":"2"//a string ":size" set to the string "2" (again, what's with the :?)

":type":"java.util.HashMap"//a string ":type" set to the string "java.util.HashMap"

":typeId":"123"//a string ":typeId" set to the string "123"
```

You can normally reference any one of these objects using "dot" notation in Javascript. The whole thing functions a lot like a Java Enum/Hashmap/ArrayList. However, because of those ":" you have throughout it is not going to work. Normally though, you could do the following ([see POC here](http://pastebin.me/5fa53b1056e5f2386a4fe358400244e2)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsonString = '{"hashcode":[], "stringMap":{"id":"50","question":"My roof"}, "size":"2", "type":"java.util.HashMap", "typeId":"123"}';
var data = eval("(" + jsonString + ")");
alert(data.stringMap.id);
</script>
```

Note that in order for that code to work, I had to remove the ":" from before "id"...

Answer (score 2):

jQuery can make AJAX requests and receive JSON objects:

```
$.getJSON(url, params, function(data, textStatus) {
    // assuming the variable "data" contains your sample json
    // you can simply get the stringMap property off it:

    var wantedValue = data.stringMap;

    // EDIT: After reading the OP's edit, you may need to "find" the property name
    // Here's how to loop over the object's properties:

    for(var propertyName in data) {
        // propertyName is a string, so you can analyze it:
        // I'll do a regexp test for property names that start with stringMap
        if(propertyName.match(/^stringMap.*/g)) {

            // use square brackets to access properties via their string name
            // if propertyName == "stringMap_0", this is equivalent to data.stringMap_0:
            wantedValue = data[propertyName];
        }
    }

    // now if you are targeting Chrome, FF3.5, or IE8
    // there is a built-in JSON object that can serialize this to a string:

    var wantedString = JSON.stringify(wantedValue); 

});
```

If you need IE7/6 compatibility, you can add the JSON object yourself, from the [JSON.org site.](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

Answer (score 1):

If you have literally a *"JSON string"* as you say, you could use a regular expression to extract that part  of the object:

```
jsonString.match(/"stringMap":({.*}),/)[1];
// returns '{":id":"50",":question":"My roof"}'
```

If you have a *JSON object*, and you want a string representation of your sub-object, you can access the `stringMap` member directly, and use a JSON library like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), to *strigify* it:

```
JSON.stringify(jsonObj.stringMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

say you get json in variable named foo, you can just write foo.stringMap like this:

```
var foo = {"hashcode":[], "stringMap":{":id":"50",":question":"My roof"},
                  ":size":"2", ":type":"java.util.HashMap", ":typeId":"123"};

alert(foo.stringMap);
```

if you want to have more options to handle it then you can use jquery's json plugin:  [jquery.json.js](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/source/browse/trunk/jquery.json.js?r=2)